# How to auto call method in class with initializing object of this class? (java)

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, subclass, superclass

```
public class Fruit {

    public String name;
    public double juiceAmount;
    public Color color;
}
```

---

```
public class Orange extends Fruit {

    public String name = "Orange";
    public double juiceAmount = 0.3 * 250;
    public Color color = Color.ORANGE;

    public void setN(){
        super.name = this.name;
    }
}
```

I want to call setN method automatically after initializing object of Orange class!! tnx for help and sorry for bad English :))

Comment: Add a constructor to this class, like `public Orange () { setN();}`

Answer (score 1):

You could just put it in a default constructor like this:

```
    public Orange() {
        this.setN();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Orange extends Fruit {
   public String name = "Orange";
   public double juiceAmount = 0.3 * 250;
   public Color color = Color.ORANGE;

   public Orange() {
     this.setN();
   }

   public void setN(){
      super.name = this.name;
   }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.